# "String or binary data would be truncated." linq exception, cant find which field has exceeded max length

Tags: linq-to-sql

String or binary data would be truncated. linq exception, cant find which field has exceeded max length.

i have around 350 fields. i checked each and every textbox maxlength with database field maxlength, everything seems to be correct, but i still get the exception.

please help

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Troubleshooting this error with 350 fields can be extremely difficult**, and SQL Server Profiler isn't much help in this case (finding the long string in the generated SQL is like finding a needle in a haystack).

So, here is an **automated way to find the actual strings that are exceeding the database size limit**.  This is a solution that's out there on the internet, in various forms.  You probably don't want to leave it in your production code, since the attribute/property searching is pretty inefficient, and it'll add extra overhead on every save. I'd just throw it in your code when you encounter this problem, and remove it when you're done.

**How it works:** it iterates over all properties on an object you're about to save, finding the properties with a LINQ to SQL `ColumnAttribute`.  Then, if the `ColumnAttribute.DbType` contains "varchar", you know it's a string and you can parse that part of the attribute to find the maximum length.

Here's how to use it:

```
foreach (object update in context.GetChangeSet().Updates)
{
    FindLongStrings(update);
}

foreach (object insert in context.GetChangeSet().Inserts)
{
    FindLongStrings(insert);
}

context.SubmitChanges();
```

And here's the method:

```
public static void FindLongStrings(object testObject)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in testObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        foreach (ColumnAttribute attribute in propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true))
        {
            if (attribute.DbType.ToLower().Contains("varchar"))
            {
                string dbType = attribute.DbType.ToLower();
                int numberStartIndex = dbType.IndexOf("varchar(") + 8;
                int numberEndIndex = dbType.IndexOf(")", numberStartIndex);
                string lengthString = dbType.Substring(numberStartIndex, (numberEndIndex - numberStartIndex));
                int maxLength = 0;
                int.TryParse(lengthString, out maxLength);

                string currentValue = (string)propInfo.GetValue(testObject, null);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue) && maxLength != 0 && currentValue.Length > maxLength)
                    Console.WriteLine(testObject.GetType().Name + "." + propInfo.Name + " " + currentValue + " Max: " + maxLength);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 12/03/2019** - 
This answer is referenced on Linqpad.net website for the same error. In Linqpad (version 5) (that uses LinqToSql) the columns are no longer listed as properties instead they are fields . Use the following to iterate through fields:

```
foreach (FieldInfo propInfo in testObject.GetType().GetFields())
...
...
         string currentValue = (string)propInfo.GetValue(testObject);
...
...
```

Comment: thanks! i was looking for such code for years! (well a year at least...)

Comment: 4 years letter and still really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! And I replaced the line `Console.WriteLine` with `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue) && maxLength != 0 && currentValue.Length > maxLength) { propInfo.SetValue(testObject, currentValue.Substring(0, maxLength)); } else if (currentValue == "") { propInfo.SetValue(testObject, null); }` This will automatically trim the string and set empty strings to `null`.

Comment: At first i thought it is due to a security concern. But seems like it has been "fixed" in SQL Server 2016 CP2+: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32909539-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated

Answer (score 3):

If you checked the max length of every textbox to the max length of every field, it is entirely possible the error is happening through a trigger. Are there triggers on the table?

Comment: If you can run sql profiler you can get the sql statement that linq generated and execute the statement yourself. You might then get a more helpful error message.

Answer (score 0):

And, hey, why not have the same solution (@shaunmartin's) in VB.Net, too? Sometimes you just gotta debug someone else's code!

Use:

```
            For Each update as Object In context.GetChangeSet().Updates
                FindLongStrings(update)
            Next

            For Each insert as Object In context.GetChangeSet().Inserts
                FindLongStrings(insert)
            Next
```

And core

```
   Public Shared Sub FindLongStrings(ByVal testObject As Object)
        Dim propInfo As PropertyInfo
        For Each propInfo In testObject.GetType().GetProperties()
            Dim attribute As ColumnAttribute
            For Each attribute In propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(ColumnAttribute), True)
                If attribute.DbType.ToLower().Contains("varchar") Then
                    Dim dbType As String = attribute.DbType.ToLower()
                    Dim numberStartIndex As Integer = dbType.IndexOf("varchar(") + 8
                    Dim numberEndIndex As Integer = dbType.IndexOf(")", numberStartIndex)
                    Dim lengthString As String = dbType.Substring(numberStartIndex, (numberEndIndex - numberStartIndex))
                    Dim maxLength As Integer = 0
                    Integer.TryParse(lengthString, maxLength)

                    Dim currentValue As String = CType(propInfo.GetValue(testObject, Nothing), String)

                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue) AndAlso maxLength <> 0 AndAlso currentValue.Length > maxLength Then
                        Console.WriteLine(testObject.GetType().Name & "." & propInfo.Name & " " & currentValue & " Max: " & maxLength)
                    End If

                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

But with a lot of data or a lot of fields this takes a lot of time for sure. The debugging side of linq is lacking - the exception thrown should tell you the field!

Answer (score -4):

i set the max length for all the 350 fields. i guess thats the only way. thanks for your support.

Comment: Actualy, shaunmartin's solution should be the accepted answer because it will help other users.

Comment: This is an incredibly bad idea from a DBA perspective. It ends up with queries getting more memory than they need, and if you're using NVARCHAR(MAX) you can no longer index the field. Have a look at this post before considering doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148398/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-always-using-nvarcharmax