# error, string or binary data would be truncated when trying to insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running data.bat file with the following lines:

```
Rem Tis batch file will populate tables

cd\program files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL
osql -U sa -P Password -d MyBusiness -i c:\data.sql
```

The contents of the data.sql file is:

```
   insert Customers
            (CustomerID, CompanyName, Phone)
             Values('101','Southwinds','19126602729')
```

There are 8 more similar lines for adding records.

When I run this with `start` > `run` > `cmd` > `c:\data.bat`, I get this error message:

```
1>2>3>4>5>....<1 row affected>
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Server SP1001, Line 1
string or binary data would be truncated.

<1 row affected>

<1 row affected>

<1 row affected>

<1 row affected>

<1 row affected>

<1 row affected>
```

Also, I am a newbie obviously, but what do `Level #`, and `state #` mean, and how do I look up error messages such as the one above: 8152?

Comment: It's worth noting that there is now an option to replace this overly generic error with a new error that includes the actual column name.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63474873/852208

Comment: If someone is encountering this error in a C# application, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71329954/8644294

Answer (score 728, accepted):

From [@gmmastros's answer](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1042136)

Whenever you see the message....

> string or binary data would be truncated

Think to yourself... The field is NOT big enough to hold my data.

Check the table structure for the customers table.  I think you'll find that the length of one or more fields is NOT big enough to hold the data you are trying to insert.  For example, if the Phone field is a varchar(8) field, and you try to put 11 characters in to it, you will get this error.

Comment: Also note that the impacted fields could be in a trigger.  Hopefully I remember this the next time this happens...

Comment: Is there any way to see in debug which field would be truncated?

Comment: This error is because your column cannot hold data after the length you fixed. Eg; `Firstname nvarchar(5) `  If you insert more than 5 characters you will get the error

Comment: Some versions of SQL Server can tell you WHICH data would have been truncated. Use `DBCC TRACEON(460);` to enable this feature. [See Aaron Bertrand's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54925/117141)

Comment: I knew it was a real SQL Exception. However, the exception message "String or binary data would be truncated"  kind of misleading ? 
it actually terminated the execution instead of Truncating the string.

Answer (score 31):

I had this issue although data length was shorter than the field length.
It turned out that the problem was having another log table (for audit trail), filled by a trigger on the main table, where the column size also had to be changed.

Comment: Thanks. Mine was because the sql column in tableA is varchar(100). It also insert to another table, in which, the column is varchar(50).

Comment: The same problem happened in my case too.
A trigger operation was the culprit.

Answer (score 20):

In one of the `INSERT` statements you are attempting to insert a too long string into a string (`varchar` or `nvarchar`) column.

If it's not obvious which `INSERT` is the offender by a mere look at the script, you could count the `<1 row affected>` lines that occur *before* the error message. The obtained number plus one gives you the statement number. In your case it seems to be the second INSERT that produces the error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, how to find which column is causing the error?

Comment: @AndréBastos: Perhaps you could submit that as a question (unless someone else has already done that, in which case there may be a ready answer to it somewhere).

Answer (score 11):

Some of your data cannot fit into your database column (small). It is not easy to find what is wrong. If you use C# and Linq2Sql, you can list the field which would be truncated:

First create helper class:

```cs
public class SqlTruncationExceptionWithDetails : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
{
    public SqlTruncationExceptionWithDetails(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException inner, DataContext context)
        : base(inner.Message + " " + GetSqlTruncationExceptionWithDetailsString(context))
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// PArt of code from following link
    /// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666954/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-linq-exception-cant-find-which-fiel
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static string GetSqlTruncationExceptionWithDetailsString(DataContext context)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (object update in context.GetChangeSet().Updates)
        {
            FindLongStrings(update, sb);
        }

        foreach (object insert in context.GetChangeSet().Inserts)
        {
            FindLongStrings(insert, sb);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static void FindLongStrings(object testObject, StringBuilder sb)
    {
        foreach (var propInfo in testObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            foreach (System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute attribute in propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute), true))
            {
                if (attribute.DbType.ToLower().Contains("varchar"))
                {
                    string dbType = attribute.DbType.ToLower();
                    int numberStartIndex = dbType.IndexOf("varchar(") + 8;
                    int numberEndIndex = dbType.IndexOf(")", numberStartIndex);
                    string lengthString = dbType.Substring(numberStartIndex, (numberEndIndex - numberStartIndex));
                    int maxLength = 0;
                    int.TryParse(lengthString, out maxLength);

                    string currentValue = (string)propInfo.GetValue(testObject, null);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue) && maxLength != 0 && currentValue.Length > maxLength)
                    {
                        //string is too long
                        sb.AppendLine(testObject.GetType().Name + "." + propInfo.Name + " " + currentValue + " Max: " + maxLength);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then prepare the wrapper for SubmitChanges:

```cs
public static class DataContextExtensions
{
    public static void SubmitChangesWithDetailException(this DataContext dataContext)
    {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666954/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-linq-exception-cant-find-which-fiel
        try
        {
            //this can failed on data truncation
            dataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }       
        catch (SqlException sqlException) //when (sqlException.Message == "String or binary data would be truncated.")
        {

            if (sqlException.Message == "String or binary data would be truncated.") //only for EN windows - if you are running different window language, invoke the sqlException.getMessage on thread with EN culture
                throw new SqlTruncationExceptionWithDetails(sqlException, dataContext);
            else
                throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Prepare global exception handler and log truncation details:

```cs
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    string message = ex.Message;
    //TODO - log to file
}
```

Finally use the code:

```cs
Datamodel.SubmitChangesWithDetailException();
```

Comment: Your solution requires the field width information to be defined in the entity model (for eg: `[Column("SomefieldName", TypeName = "varchar(10)")]` annotation in `SomefieldName` property), so unfortunately this didn't work out for me. So I went ahead and created methods to get the column width information **directly from the database table**. If someone is interested, check out the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71329954/8644294

Answer (score 11):

Just want to contribute with additional information: I had the same issue and it was because of the field wasn't big enough for the incoming data and this thread helped me to solve it (the top answer clarifies it all).

BUT it is very important to know what are the possible reasons that may cause it.

In my case i was creating the table with a field like this:

```
Select '' as  Period, * From Transactions Into #NewTable
```

Therefore the field "Period" had a length of Zero and causing the Insert operations to fail. I changed it to "XXXXXX" that is the length of the incoming data and it now worked properly (because field now had a lentgh of 6).

I hope this help anyone with same issue :)

Answer (score 8):

Another situation in which you can get this error is the following:

I had the same error and the reason was that in an INSERT statement that received data from an UNION, the order of the columns was different from the original table. If you change the order in #table3 to a, b, c, you will fix the error.

```
select a, b, c into #table1
from #table0

insert into #table1
    select a, b, c from #table2
    union
    select a, c, b from #table3
```

Answer (score 8):

on sql server you can use SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF like this:

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XRAYGOAT\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog='Healthy Care';Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    using cmd = new SqlCommand("", conn, trans))
                    { 

                    cmd.CommandText = "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd.CommandText = "YOUR INSERT HERE";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                    cmd.CommandText = "SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    trans.Commit();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    trans.Rollback();
                }

            }

            conn.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Using `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` turned out to be exactly the diagnostic tool that I needed. Not something I plan to use in production though.

Answer (score 7):

Also had this problem occurring on the web application surface. 
Eventually found out that the same error message comes from the SQL update statement in the specific table.

**Finally then figured out that the column definition in the relating history table(s) did not map the original table column length of `nvarchar` types in some specific cases.**

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. The **length** of my column was too short.

What you can do is either **increase** the length or **shorten** the text you want to put in the database.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, even after increasing the size of the problematic columns in the table.

**tl;dr: The length of the matching columns in corresponding Table Types may also need to be increased.**

In my case, the error was coming from the Data Export service in Microsoft Dynamics CRM, which allows CRM data to be synced to an SQL Server DB or Azure SQL DB.

After a lengthy investigation, I concluded that the Data Export service must be using [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine):

> You can use table-valued parameters to send multiple rows of data to a Transact-SQL statement or a routine, such as a stored procedure or function, without creating a temporary table or many parameters.

As you can see in the documentation above, Table Types are used to create the data ingestion procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE LocationTableType AS TABLE (...);
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertProductionLocation
  @TVP LocationTableType READONLY
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to alter a Table Type, so it has to be dropped & recreated entirely. Since my table has over 300 fields (), I created a query to facilitate the creation of the corresponding Table Type based on the table's columns definition (just replace `[table_name]` with your table's name):

```
SELECT 'CREATE TYPE [table_name]Type AS TABLE (' + STRING_AGG(CAST(field AS VARCHAR(max)), ',' + CHAR(10)) + ');' AS create_type
FROM (
  SELECT TOP 5000 COLUMN_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE
      + IIF(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL, '', CONCAT('(', IIF(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1, 'max', CONCAT(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,'')), ')'))
      + IIF(DATA_TYPE = 'decimal', CONCAT('(', NUMERIC_PRECISION, ',', NUMERIC_SCALE, ')'), '')
      AS field
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = '[table_name]'
  ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION) AS T;
```

After updating the Table Type, the Data Export service started functioning properly once again! :)

Answer (score 3):

When I tried to execute my stored procedure I had the same problem because the size of the column that I need to add some data is shorter than the data I want to add.

You can increase the size of the column data type or reduce the length of your data.

Answer (score 2):

**A 2016/2017 update will show you the bad value and column.**

[image]

A new trace flag will swap the old error for a new 2628 error and will print out the column and offending value.  Traceflag 460 is available in the latest cumulative update for 2016 and 2017:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4468101/optional-replacement-for-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated

Just make sure that after you've installed the CU that you enable the trace flag, either globally/permanently on the server:
[image]

...or with DBCC TRACEON:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

Another situation, in which this error may occur is in 
SQL Server Management Studio. If you have "text" or "ntext" fields in your table,
no matter what kind of field you are updating (for example bit or integer).
Seems that the Studio does not load entire "ntext" fields and also updates ALL fields instead of the modified one.
To solve the problem, exclude "text" or "ntext" fields from the query in Management Studio

Comment: Please consider rephrasing your answer by adding commas, periods and fixing your grammar errors.

Comment: This answer helped me - my nvarchar fields are large enough but I  have an ntext field. Seems to be some error in Management Studio / SMSS.

Answer (score 1):

This Error Comes only When any of your field length is greater than the field length specified in sql server database table structure.

To overcome this issue you have to reduce the length of the field Value .
Or to increase the length of database table field .

Answer (score 0):

[Kevin Pope's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493055/kevin-pope) comment under the accepted answer was what I needed.

The problem, in my case, was that I had triggers defined on my table that would insert update/insert transactions into an audit table, but the audit table had a data type mismatch where a column with `VARCHAR(MAX)` in the original table was stored as `VARCHAR(1)` in the audit table, so my triggers were failing when I would insert anything greater than `VARCHAR(1)` in the original table column and I would get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different tactic, fields that are allocated 8K in some places.  Here only about 50/100 are used.

```
declare @NVPN_list as table 
nvpn            varchar(50)
,nvpn_revision  varchar(5)
,nvpn_iteration INT
,mpn_lifecycle  varchar(30)
,mfr            varchar(100)
,mpn            varchar(50)
,mpn_revision   varchar(5)
,mpn_iteration  INT
-- ...
) INSERT INTO @NVPN_LIST 
SELECT  left(nvpn           ,50)    as nvpn
        ,left(nvpn_revision ,10)    as nvpn_revision
        ,nvpn_iteration
        ,left(mpn_lifecycle ,30)
        ,left(mfr           ,100)
        ,left(mpn           ,50)
        ,left(mpn_revision  ,5)
        ,mpn_iteration
        ,left(mfr_order_num ,50)
FROM [DASHBOARD].[dbo].[mpnAttributes] (NOLOCK) mpna
```

I wanted speed, since I have 1M total records, and load 28K of them.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be due to less field size than your entered data.

For e.g. if you have data type `nvarchar(7)` and if your value is 'aaaaddddf' then error is shown as:

> string or binary data would be truncated

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't beat SQL Server on this.

You can insert into a new table like this:

```
select foo, bar
into tmp_new_table_to_dispose_later
from my_table
```

and **compare the table definition with the real table** you want to insert the data into.

Sometime it's helpful sometimes it's not.

If you try inserting in the final/real table from that temporary table it may just work (due to data conversion working differently than SSMS for example).

**Another alternative is to insert the data in chunks**, instead of inserting everything immediately you insert with `top 1000` and you repeat the process, till you find a chunk with an error. At least you have better visibility on what's not fitting into the table.