# How to select record of different data type from sql column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two a table and a view . The table if of two rows of datatypes nvarchar and money. I have being updating the table by selecting from the view like below.

```
Insert into MyTable
    Select * from MyView
```

Recently, this update fails due to an error "String or binary data would be truncated." However, when i modified by select statement to something like.

```
Select * from Myview WHERE Column is not null 

OR

Select * from Myview WHERE Column > 0
```

The above work with a warning saying `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.` . It occurred to me that may may be one of the null value records contain something that's not null. My table column is of money type and accept null. I presumed the error may be due to something that's not of money data type. The record is huge. Is there any way i can filter and return those aliens records?

I also i learnt that i can eliminate the error by turning ANSI WARNING SETTION ON & OFF [Here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/surpress-string-or-binary-data-would-be-/) . My concern is wouldn't that result in loss of data. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to tell us how the tables and views look like and whats in there. IS for example the nvarchar of the view longer than the one of the table?

Comment: OMG. That's exactly what i overlooked sir. The table nvarchar column is of 20 length and my view nvarchar column is of 25 length . Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the data in some column in table MyView exceeds the limit of the corresponding one in table MyTable

Comment: LOL. Thats what happened sir. Thank you for your time. Was focusing on the wrong column since.

Answer (score 2):

String or binary data would be truncated happened because the data coming from the MyView is larger than the column size in MyTable

Use

```
Select Max(Len(FieldName)) From MyTable
```

to check the maximum length of the nvarchar field in the MyTable
Or you can use Left when inserting data something Llike this

```
Insert into MyTable
Select Left(FieldName,50), Column1 from MyView
```

Note the 50 should be the size of the nvarchar field in MyTable

Answer (score 2):

String or binary data would be truncated is a very common error. It usually happens when we try to insert any data in string (varchar,nvarchar,char,nchar) data type column which is more than size of the column. So you need to check the data size with respect to the column width and identify which column is creating problem and fix it.

Here is another thread of the same problem as yours in stackoverflow.
[string or binary data would be truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591473/error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-when-trying-to-)

Hope this will help.
Regards