# Execute UPDATE command

Tags: c#, sql

I wrote that to update my SQL table.

```
        mycmd.CommandText = "UPDATE savedinfo SET User_id='" + Login.GetUserID().ToString() + "', Date='" + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + "', Evaluate='" + activeEvaluate.ToString() + "', TimeStart='" + dtCurrentTime1.ToLongTimeString() + "', TimeEnd='" +dtCurrentTime2.ToLongTimeString() + "' , Salary= '" + todaySalary.Text +"'";
        mycmd.Connection = con;
        mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When getting to `mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` I got an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

What is the problem here?
Thanks

Comment: You should be using a parameterized query.

Comment: What does the Commandtext look like for a record that is failing, and how does that compare to the table schema?

Comment: As the [past][1] says, The field is NOT big enough to hold your data.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591473/error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-when-trying-to-insert

Comment: check the size of columns in table and your input.

Comment: Also you don't need to call `.ToString()` if the left-hand argument of the assign value(s) is a string, since it's called implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error implies that you are attempting to insert a value which is to big for the column length within the database. Please look through your database schema and identify which column is causing the issue.

Looking at the snippet of code I have a few other observations which maybe of some help.

Does the Update statement require a where clause?

Do use parameterised queries as this will help against SQL injection attacks.

Using statement are very helpful in clearing and cleaning up an objects, in this case a using statement help managing the open connections to the database.

If you wish to check for valid string lengths before sending them to the database check the arguments before creating connections etc. ideally these check would be carried out in your business logic layer.

```
          if (activeEvaluate.Length > 5)
          {
             throw new ArgumentException("activeEvaluate");
          }

          using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
          {
               using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
               {
                 cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE savedinfo set User_id= @UserId, Date = @Date, Evaluate = @Evaluate, TimeStart = @TimeStart, TimeEnd = @TimeEnd, Salary = @Salary ";

                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Login.GetUserID());
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date",  DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Evaluate", activeEvaluate.ToString());
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeStart", dtCurrentTime1.ToLongTimeString());
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeEnd", dtCurrentTime2.ToLongTimeString());
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", todaySalary.Text);
                 cmd.Connection.Open();
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
            }
```