# How could I get "String or binary data would be truncated" when the value being updated is not too long?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, visual-studio-debugging, truncated

On calling a Stored Proc to retrieve values, in some cases (not all - it all works fine with some data), I get a "String or binary data would be truncated" err msg .

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591473/error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-when-trying-to-insert), that happens when you try to insert data that is too long, or when you try to add data out-of-order; the latter can't be the problem, because it does work in some cases. It's apprently a data problem.

The exeption message says line 75 of "priceUsageVariance" (my Stored Procedure) is the culprit:

Line 75 of "priceUsageVariance" is:

```
WHERE ItemCode='X'
```

Here is an excerpt from that Stored Procedure, to show more context (the ostensibly problematic line is the last one):

```
. . .
CREATE TABLE #TEMPCOMBINED(
  PlatypusNo VARCHAR(6),
  PlatypusName VARCHAR(50),
  ItemCode VARCHAR(15),
  PlatypusItemCode VARCHAR(20),
  DuckbillDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50),
  PlatypusDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(200),
  WEEK1USAGE DECIMAL(18,2),
  WEEK2USAGE DECIMAL(18,2),
  USAGEVARIANCE AS WEEK2USAGE - WEEK1USAGE,
  WEEK1PRICE DECIMAL(18,2),
  WEEK2PRICE DECIMAL(18,2),
  PRICEVARIANCE AS WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE,
  PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE AS CAST((WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE) / NULLIF(WEEK1PRICE,0) AS DECIMAL(18,5))
);

INSERT INTO #TEMPCOMBINED (PlatypusNo, PlatypusName, ItemCode, PlatypusItemCode, DuckbillDESCRIPTION, PlatypusDESCRIPTION,
WEEK1USAGE, WEEK2USAGE, WEEK1PRICE, WEEK2PRICE)
SELECT T1.PlatypusNo, T1.PlatypusName, 'X', T1.PlatypusITEMCODE, NULL, T1.DESCRIPTION, T1.WEEK1USAGE, T2.WEEK2USAGE, 
T1.WEEK1PRICE, T2.WEEK2PRICE
FROM #TEMP1 T1
LEFT JOIN #TEMP2 T2 ON T1.PlatypusITEMCODE = T2.PlatypusITEMCODE

    UPDATE #TEMPCOMBINED SET ItemCode = ISNULL(
    (SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode 
     FROM MasterPlatypusUnitMapping 
     WHERE Unit=@Unit
     AND PlatypusNo=#TEMPCOMBINED.PlatypusNo 
     AND PlatypusItemCode = #TEMPCOMBINED.PlatypusItemCode 
     AND ItemCode IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM UnitProducts WHERE Unit=@Unit)),'X'
    )
    WHERE ItemCode='X'
. . .
```

I don't see how this problem is even possible - The ItemCode field is either being updated with an ItemCode value from the MasterPlatypusUnitMapping table - which is a VarChar(15), the same as the corresponding field in my #TEMPCOMBINE table - or with an 'X'. How could either value be too large?

Is the line number given valid/reliable? Is there a way to step through the Stored Procedure as it's being processed?

Is there some kind of workaround so that I can prevent this exception from fouling up the works?

### UPDATE

Responding to Shnugo's suggestion/request, here is the entire SP:

Here it is:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[priceAndUsageVariance]
    @Unit varchar(25),
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS 

DECLARE @Week1End datetime = DATEADD(Day, 6, @BegDate);
DECLARE @Week2Begin datetime = DATEADD(Day, 7, @BegDate);

// temp1 holds some values for the first week
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1
(
    MemberNo VARCHAR(6),
    MemberName VARCHAR(50),
    MEMBERITEMCODE VARCHAR(25),
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50),
    WEEK1USAGE DECIMAL(18,2),
    WEEK1PRICE DECIMAL(18,2)
);

INSERT INTO #TEMP1 (MemberNo, MemberName, MEMBERITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION,   
    WEEK1USAGE, WEEK1PRICE)
SELECT INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName, ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, SUM(QTYSHIPPED), 
PRICE 
FROM INVOICEDETAIL INVD
JOIN MEMBERS M ON INVD.MEMBERNO = M.MEMBERNO
WHERE UNIT=@UNIT AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @BEGDATE AND @Week1End
GROUP BY ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName

// temp2 holds some values for the second week
CREATE TABLE #TEMP2
(
    MemberNo VARCHAR(6),
    MemberName VARCHAR(50),
    MEMBERITEMCODE VARCHAR(25),
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50),
    WEEK2USAGE DECIMAL(18,2),
    WEEK2PRICE DECIMAL(18,2)
);

INSERT INTO #TEMP2 (MemberNo, MemberName, MEMBERITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, 
    WEEK2USAGE, WEEK2PRICE)
SELECT INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName, ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, SUM(QTYSHIPPED),  
    PRICE 
FROM INVOICEDETAIL INVD
JOIN MEMBERS M ON INVD.MEMBERNO = M.MEMBERNO
WHERE UNIT=@UNIT AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @ENDDATE
GROUP BY ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName

// Now tempCombined gets the shared values from temp1 as well as the unique 
    vals from temp1 and the unique vals from temp2
CREATE TABLE #TEMPCOMBINED(
  MemberNo VARCHAR(6),
  MemberName VARCHAR(50),
  ItemCode VARCHAR(15),
  MemberItemCode VARCHAR(20),
  PlatypusDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50),
  MEMBERDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(200),
  WEEK1USAGE DECIMAL(18,2),
  WEEK2USAGE DECIMAL(18,2),
  USAGEVARIANCE AS WEEK2USAGE - WEEK1USAGE,
  WEEK1PRICE DECIMAL(18,2),
  WEEK2PRICE DECIMAL(18,2),
  PRICEVARIANCE AS WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE,
  PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE AS CAST((WEEK2PRICE - WEEK1PRICE) / 
    NULLIF(WEEK1PRICE,0) AS DECIMAL(18,5))
);

INSERT INTO #TEMPCOMBINED (MemberNo, MemberName, ItemCode, MemberItemCode, 
PlatypusDESCRIPTION, MEMBERDESCRIPTION,
WEEK1USAGE, WEEK2USAGE, WEEK1PRICE, WEEK2PRICE)
SELECT T1.MemberNo, T1.MemberName, 'X', T1.MEMBERITEMCODE, NULL, 
   T1.DESCRIPTION, 
   T1.WEEK1USAGE, T2.WEEK2USAGE, 
   T1.WEEK1PRICE, T2.WEEK2PRICE
FROM #TEMP1 T1
LEFT JOIN #TEMP2 T2 ON T1.MEMBERITEMCODE = T2.MEMBERITEMCODE

// Now some mumbo-jumbo is performed to display the "general" description 
       rather than the "localized" description
UPDATE #TEMPCOMBINED SET ItemCode = ISNULL(
(SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode 
 FROM MasterMemberUnitMapping 
 WHERE Unit=@Unit
 AND MemberNo=#TEMPCOMBINED.MemberNo 
 AND MemberItemCode = #TEMPCOMBINED.MemberItemCode 
 AND ItemCode IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM UnitProducts WHERE Unit=@Unit)),'X'
)
WHERE ItemCode='X'

UPDATE #TEMPCOMBINED SET ItemCode = ISNULL(
(SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode FROM MasterMemberMapping WHERE 
 MemberNo=#TEMPCOMBINED.MemberNo AND MemberItemCode + PackType = 
    #TEMPCOMBINED.MemberItemCode ),'X'
) 
WHERE ItemCode='X'

UPDATE #TEMPCOMBINED SET PlatypusDESCRIPTION = ISNULL(MP.Description,'')
FROM #TEMPCOMBINED TC 
INNER JOIN MasterProducts MP ON MP.Itemcode=TC.ItemCode

// finally, what is hoped to be the desired amalgamation is returned
SELECT TC.PlatypusDESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName, TC.WEEK1USAGE, TC.WEEK2USAGE, 
    TC.USAGEVARIANCE, TC.WEEK1PRICE, TC.WEEK2PRICE, TC.PRICEVARIANCE, 
    TC.PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE
FROM #TEMPCOMBINED TC
ORDER BY TC.PlatypusDESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName;
```

### UPDATE

I'm trying to modernize this as well, adapting Schnugo's code, but with this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[priceAndUsageVarianceTVF]
(
    @Unit varchar(25),
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
WITH Dates aS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(Day, 6, @BegDate) AS Week1End
          ,DATEADD(Day, 7, @BegDate) AS Week2Begin
)
,Temp1 AS
(
    SELECT INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName, ITEMCODE AS MEMBERITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, SUM(QTYSHIPPED) AS WEEK1USAGE, 
    PRICE AS WEEK1PRICE
    FROM INVOICEDETAIL INVD
    JOIN MEMBERS M ON INVD.MEMBERNO = M.MEMBERNO
    WHERE UNIT=@UNIT AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @BEGDATE AND (SELECT Week1End FROM Dates)
    GROUP BY ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName
)
,Temp2 AS
(
    SELECT INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName, ITEMCODE AS MEMBERITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, SUM(QTYSHIPPED) AS WEEK2USAGE,  
        PRICE AS WEEK2PRICE
    FROM INVOICEDETAIL INVD
    JOIN MEMBERS M ON INVD.MEMBERNO = M.MEMBERNO
    WHERE UNIT=@UNIT AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN (SELECT Week2Begin FROM Dates) AND @ENDDATE
    GROUP BY ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName
)
,TempCombined AS
(
    SELECT T1.MemberNo, T1.MemberName, T1.MEMBERITEMCODE, NULL AS PLATYPUSDESCRIPTION, 
       T1.DESCRIPTION, 
       T1.WEEK1USAGE, T2.WEEK2USAGE,       
       T1.WEEK1PRICE, T2.WEEK2PRICE    
    FROM Temp1 T1
    LEFT JOIN Temp2 T2 ON T1.MEMBERITEMCODE = T2.MEMBERITEMCODE
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TC.PLATYPUSDESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName) AS RowInxToGetASortOrder,
    ISNULL(MP.Description,'') AS PLATYPUSDESCRIPTION, 
    TC.MemberName, TC.WEEK1USAGE, TC.WEEK2USAGE, 
    TC.USAGEVARIANCE AS T2.WEEK2USAGE - T1.WEEK1USAGE,
    TC.WEEK1PRICE, TC.WEEK2PRICE, 
    TC.PRICEVARIANCE AS T2.WEEK2PRICE - T1.WEEK1PRICE,
    TC.PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE AS CAST((T2.WEEK2PRICE - T1.WEEK1PRICE) / NULLIF(T1.WEEK1PRICE,0) AS DECIMAL(18,5))
FROM TempCombined TC
LEFT JOIN Temp2 T2 ON T1.MEMBERITEMCODE = T2.MEMBERITEMCODE
--LEFT JOIN MasterProducts MP ON MP.Itemcode=ISNULL(ItemCode_Try1.ItemCode, ItemCode_Try2.ItemCode)
LEFT JOIN MasterProducts MP ON MP.Itemcode=ISNULL(ItemCode_Try1.ItemCode, ItemCode_Try2.ItemCode)
CROSS APPLY
(
 SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode 
 FROM MasterMemberUnitMapping 
 WHERE Unit=@Unit
 AND MemberNo=TC.MemberNo 
 AND MemberItemCode = TC.MemberItemCode 
 AND ItemCode IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM UnitProducts WHERE Unit=@Unit)
) AS ItemCode_Try1(ItemCode)
CROSS APPLY
(
 SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode 
 FROM MasterMemberMapping 
 WHERE MemberNo=TC.MemberNo 
   AND MemberItemCode + PackType = TC.MemberItemCode 
) AS ItemCode_Try2(ItemCode)
;
```

...I'm getting the following err msgs:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure priceAndUsageVarianceTVF, Line 45
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure priceAndUsageVarianceTVF, Line 61
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure priceAndUsageVarianceTVF, Line 68
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Msg 102 is on this line:

```
TC.USAGEVARIANCE AS T2.WEEK2USAGE - T1.WEEK1USAGE,
```

(with red squiggles beneath T2.WEEK2USAGE)

Msg 156 is on the final two "AS" lines, namely this:

```
 AS ItemCode_Try1(ItemCode)
```

...and this:

```
) AS ItemCode_Try2(ItemCode)
```

Comment: can you  try to check len('field') and add it against each column

Comment: Hi, this question is worth an upvote, and: It was me who pushed you over the 10k! Congrats :-)

Comment: But back to work... No, the line numbers very often do not give you too much help. If it is not to much, you might post the full SP... Such troubles can make real headache... Very hard to find...

Comment: @Shnugo: Thanks; you will forever live in infamy for that (> 10K)! I am adding an update with the whole SP.

Comment: @TheGameiswar: Can you give an example of len("field")? I'm not familiar with that. I'm also wondering if I should add an IsNull to every field insert, just to be on the safer side.

Comment: Hi, I just saw that you were around... I'm curious: Was it the concatenation of `MemberItemCode +PackType` as suggested in my answer? Did my answer help you?

Comment: Looking at your error, you can't do things like this: `TC.USAGEVARIANCE AS T2.WEEK2USAGE - T1.WEEK1USAGE`. If you're just trying to include, in your result set, a column called `USAGEVARIANCE`, you can do this: `USAGEVARIANCE = T2.WEEK2USAGE - T1.WEEK1USAGE`

Comment: That is a calculated field, as are the other two "Variance" columns. They work. They do not have table aliases prepended, though; that one is simply, "USAGEVARIANCE AS WEEK2USAGE - WEEK1USAGE"

Comment: @JasonWhitish: Oh, I see, you're taking about the alternate version in the Update. I'll try that again.

Comment: @JasonWhitish: When I change the "AS" to "=" on "TC.PRICEVARIANCE = T2.WEEK2PRICE - T1.WEEK1PRICE" I get, "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Comment: You can't have a two part name, either. You have to remove the `tc.` alias as well. You are literally defining the column you want to call  `PRICEVARIANCE` in your result; it's not part of the CTE result you've aliased `TC`.

Comment: In the original version of the SP, the calculated fields are working just fine, and that's how they are defined; e.g.: "USAGEVARIANCE AS WEEK2USAGE - WEEK1USAGE" It is only on my derivation of Shnugo's code where I'm getting the errors.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon as you'll find in my answer it is one thing to define a computed column in a temp-table and another thing to set an alias to an output column. For this you have two alternatives: 1) `SomeValue AS AliasName` where AliasName might be set in boundaries due to invalid characters, or 2) `AliasName=SomeValue`. The Value may be a multipart name (`soure.SomeValue`), the alias is just a new name (or in other words: only the last part of the multipart name)

Comment: @Shnugo: I don't know what you mean by,, "might be set in boundaries"

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, boundaries are `SomeValue AS [A name with spaces]` or `SomeValue AS 'another.name.with.invalid.characters' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was increase the size of one of the Description values to match that of the other, going from this:

```
DuckbillDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50),
PlatypusDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(200),
```

...to this:

```
DuckbillDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(200),
PlatypusDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(200),
```

...and I also prepended **IsNull()** to every field, so that I always get a zero, and empty string, or a "boo boo" string, never a null value.

Comment: Glad, that you found a solution, but: How should one find this... the column `DuckbillDESCRIPTION` is only mentioned in your first post, but not in the "full SP" you posted later...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was a bogus name. Any reference to "duckbill" or "platypus" is just a form of mammalian obfuscation.

Comment: I think you might be a quite funny guy :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

What debugging process I follow in such situation is, I take this part of stored procedure code in separate script and run it there to reach to the root cause.

You can follow below steps if you are not sure which line or column is exactly causing this error of truncation.

1. You can comment the same line which shows as an issue (e.g. where itemcode = 'x') while running the procedure and run the script to make sure whether it's the actual line of error or not.
2. If after commenting the line still if you are getting truncation error that means error is somewhere else. You can comment one by one column in the select statement and run the script every time to find out which column is exactly throwing this error.

I am not sure what is the table definition of #temp1 and #temp2, you can cross verify it against #tempcombine to confirm matching datatype and length.

Comment: Thanks, Hiren; I added the entire SP in an Update.

Comment: Well, that remains to be seen; I'm still testing it.

Answer (score 1):

still I don't know the reason, it might be where you concatenate `MemberItemCode + PackType` ...

But:

Such a StoredProcedure is very *old fashioned* This is a classical example, where an inlineable (ad-hoc) table valued function would be a much better approach.

Without knowing your database and without a chance to test something, the following suggestion will not work "out of the box" for sure, but you might get an idea how you could speed up things enormously. As a side effect you would get rid of the error mentioned as the query engine would deal with the original columns and would not have to copy values from one place to a (eventually smaller) column with truncation effects:

I'm sure, that this structure is far away from the optimum, but without knowing details I had no other chance than to copy and adapt the code blocks you defined in your SP. Especially where it comes to your "mumbo-jumbo" :-) I'm not quite sure, if I got the idea correctly...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[priceAndUsageVariance]
(
    @Unit varchar(25),
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
WITH Dates aS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(Day, 6, @BegDate) AS Week1End
          ,DATEADD(Day, 7, @BegDate) AS Week2Begin
)
,Temp1 AS
(
    SELECT INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName, ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, SUM(QTYSHIPPED), 
    PRICE 
    FROM INVOICEDETAIL INVD
    JOIN MEMBERS M ON INVD.MEMBERNO = M.MEMBERNO
    WHERE UNIT=@UNIT AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @BEGDATE AND (SELECT Week1End FROM Dates)
    GROUP BY ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName
)
,Temp2 AS
(
    SELECT INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName, ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, SUM(QTYSHIPPED),  
        PRICE 
    FROM INVOICEDETAIL INVD
    JOIN MEMBERS M ON INVD.MEMBERNO = M.MEMBERNO
    WHERE UNIT=@UNIT AND INVOICEDATE BETWEEN (SELECT Week2Begin FROM Dates) AND @ENDDATE
    GROUP BY ITEMCODE, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, INVD.MEMBERNO, MemberName
)
,TempCombined AS
(
    SELECT T1.MemberNo, T1.MemberName, 'X', T1.MEMBERITEMCODE, NULL, 
       T1.DESCRIPTION, 
       T1.WEEK1USAGE, T2.WEEK2USAGE, 
       T1.WEEK1PRICE, T2.WEEK2PRICE
    FROM Temp1 T1
    LEFT JOIN Temp2 T2 ON T1.MEMBERITEMCODE = T2.MEMBERITEMCODE
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TC.PlatypusDESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName) AS RowInxToGetASortOrder,

    ISNULL(MP.Description,'') AS PlatypusDESCRIPTION, 

    TC.MemberName, TC.WEEK1USAGE, TC.WEEK2USAGE, 
    TC.USAGEVARIANCE, TC.WEEK1PRICE, TC.WEEK2PRICE, TC.PRICEVARIANCE, 
    TC.PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE
FROM TempCombined TC
LEFT JOIN MasterProducts MP ON MP.Itemcode=ISNULL(ItemCode_Try1.ItemCode,ItemCode_Try2.ItemCode)
CROSS APPLY
(
 SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode 
 FROM MasterMemberUnitMapping 
 WHERE Unit=@Unit
 AND MemberNo=TC.MemberNo 
 AND MemberItemCode = TC.MemberItemCode 
 AND ItemCode IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM UnitProducts WHERE Unit=@Unit)
) AS ItemCode_Try1(ItemCode)
CROSS APPLY
(
 SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode 
 FROM MasterMemberMapping 
 WHERE MemberNo=TC.MemberNo 
   AND MemberItemCode + PackType = TC.MemberItemCode 
) AS ItemCode_Try2(ItemCode)
;
```

Comment: I don't know if this: ISNULL(ItemCode_Try1.ItemCode, ItemCode_Try2.ItemCode) was pseudoSQL, but even when I changed it to this: ISNULL(T1.ITEMCODE, T2.ITEMCODE) and using "'X' AS ITEMCODE" above that, it failed

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, no it was meant as it is written. Its the APPLY's alias. Still it is pseudocode as it is not testable vor me ... This is your "mumbo-jumbo" :-)

Comment: Please see my Update 2.

Answer (score 1):

this is an answer to your attempt to modernize your approach.

You try to set wrong alias names in your central SELECT

Change it to this, and it will have no syntax problems anymore:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TC.PLATYPUSDESCRIPTION, TC.MemberName) AS RowInxToGetASortOrder,
    ISNULL(MP.Description,'') AS PLATYPUSDESCRIPTION, 
    TC.MemberName, TC.WEEK1USAGE, TC.WEEK2USAGE, 
    T2.WEEK2USAGE - T1.WEEK1USAGE AS TC_USAGEVARIANCE,
    TC.WEEK1PRICE, TC.WEEK2PRICE, 
    T2.WEEK2PRICE - T1.WEEK1PRICE AS TC_PRICEVARIANCE,
    CAST((T2.WEEK2PRICE - T1.WEEK1PRICE) / NULLIF(T1.WEEK1PRICE,0) AS DECIMAL(18,5)) AS TC_PRICEVARIANCEPERCENTAGE
FROM TempCombined TC
```

But - of course - I cannot know, if it delivers the correct result...

Comment: Danke, ich werde es bald einmal probieren.

Comment: Sie sprechen Deutsch? Schön! Es wird mich freuen, wenn Sie mir helfen, die 10.000 auch bald zu erreichen :-)

Comment: Ja, ich habe Deutsch vor 30 Jahre gelernt; jetzt lerne ich Spanisch.

Comment: Also in 30 Jahren dann in Spanisch :-)

Comment: So do you mean (by the code above) to leave out the LEFT JOINS?...no, that can't be...

Comment: @B.ClayShannon No, you'll need them to join the CTEs... It's just the propper way to write the column's aliases to get rid of syntax errors.

Comment: I'm still getting errors on the "AS ItemCode_Try1.ItemCode" and "AS ItemCode_Try2.ItemCode" bits ("Incorrect syntx near '.'" for the first one, and "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS' for the second one).

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Do you have dots there? If this is the part where the CROSS APPLY gets an alias (so the last few lines), it must be written as I've done it in my answer: `AS ItemCode_Try1(ItemCode)` In your select this will be taken like a table's name and you can read its column with the multipart syntax `ItemCode_Try1.ItemCode`