# C# ASP.NET Registration page won't update database anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

My registration page (C# ASP.NET on VS 2015) updated a few entries in my SQL Server database, then I changed the database, updated the code a bit (updated `web.config` string, etc) and now it only shows this error:

> Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at Registration.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\718358\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\Registration2\Registration.aspx.cs:line 61 ClientConnectionId:d0e00199-8bf8-435b-a2ea-03d6f5c8dc40 Error Number:8152,State:13,Class:16
>   Registration

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "SELECT count(*) FROM Customers WHERE CustUserName='" + txtCustUserName.Text + "'";

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User already exists");
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            string insertQuery = "INSERT into Customers (CustUserName, CustPassword, CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustAddress, CustCity, CustProv, CustPostal, CustCountry, CustHomePhone, CustBusPhone, CustEmail) values (@custUsername ,@custPassword ,@custFirstName ,@custLastName ,@custAddress ,@custCity ,@custProv ,@custPostal, @custCountry ,@custHomePhone ,@custBusPhone ,@custEmail)";

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custUsername", txtCustUserName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custPassword", txtCustPassword.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custFirstName", txtCustFirstName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custLastName", txtCustLastName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custAddress", txtCustAddress.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custCity", txtCustCity.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custProv", txtCustProv.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custPostal", txtCustPostal.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custCountry", txtCustCountry.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custHomePhone", txtCustHomePhone.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custBusPhone", txtCustBusPhone.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custEmail", txtCustEmail.Text);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
            Response.Write("Registration is successful" );

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:"+ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check if the field in the database can hold your data. Please see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5591928/3881866)

Comment: Your error flows in Insert statement? if so, that means the input is too long, also, try stating which line the error flows.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado  all the fields are varchar, I just input similar things as I did when the entry was accepted by database and it now it doesn't work.

Comment: @User2012384  My input has less characters than the limit the fields have, it's quite little, I wrote "test" in the fields.

Comment: Check the max length of your table column in the database. varchar(20) will only accept 20 characters

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado You're a genius! I double checked the limits, and lo and behold one of the fields has a 3 characters limit, and that was the cause of the error. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, **one or more of the fields is getting a value that is longer than the corresponding column**.  You should double check the lengths of the columns.  Without knowing more details it's impossible to say how or why changing your database caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace The Following Code with Your Existing One : -- )

---

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "INSERT into Customers (CustUserName, CustPassword, CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustAddress, CustCity, CustProv, CustPostal, CustCountry, CustHomePhone, CustBusPhone, CustEmail) values (@custUsername ,@custPassword ,@custFirstName ,@custLastName ,@custAddress ,@custCity ,@custProv ,@custPostal, @custCountry ,@custHomePhone ,@custBusPhone ,@custEmail)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custUsername", txtCustUserName.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custPassword", txtCustPassword.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custFirstName", txtCustFirstName.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custLastName", txtCustLastName.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custAddress", txtCustAddress.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custCity", txtCustCity.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custProv", txtCustProv.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custPostal", txtCustPostal.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custCountry", txtCustCountry.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custHomePhone", txtCustHomePhone.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custBusPhone", txtCustBusPhone.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("@custEmail", txtCustEmail.Text);

            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
            Response.Write("Registration is successful" );

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:"+ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

You were creating a small flaw just replace AddWithValue with Add only
And also Add The following line "com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;"

Comment: I still get an error:                                        Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still getting the error then following may be the reasons :

**Error** : (String or binary data would be truncated)

**Reason**  :

1) Data you are entering in the database field is of different type.

2) Data you are entering in database field is bigger in size than the declared one.

3)You are not converting the incoming data form to appropriate field type.

**My Guess** : (You're Directly Entering Data as From Fields)

**Remedies** :

1) Convert string data to String (concat .toString() in last of input recieved) + Convert data according to other data types as well like int/float/etc

2) Increase the field input Size in Database (Ex: City(25) to city(MAX))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.  @JohnEphraimTugado answered the question. The error occurred because the field received input larger than the limit accepted by the field.

Comment: Please do not post comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error speaks out of itself, there is a field in DB which is getting more data to accommodate than it's limit (explaining in lame language).
Please check the field, make sure you do either of the two :

1. Trim the data string being sent to the DB to a particular length, below the character limit in the DB.
2. Change the limit of the DB field, so that it can accommodate more length.