# False error message for binary data truncation(Msg 8152)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am getting false error message while data inserting to some table.

The data type for the field is `Varchar(20)` and the data being inserted has max 
data length is 6.

I don't understand where's the issue is. Although I can avoid this by adding

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```

But it'd be workaround not a solution:

[image: Details]

Comment: sh.Name is probably nVARCHAR?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error, string or binary data would be truncated when trying to insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591473/error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-when-trying-to-insert)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger If you don't understand the problem then atleast don't comment. Anyone can say that "field length is smaller than the insert value".

Comment: `sh.name` is type of `sysname` - basically `nvarchar(128)` while your schemaname-type is `varchar`. So that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your column SchemaName **maxlength** property **smaller** then value which you going to insert.

Update your column length as per your data.

```
ALTER TABLE Temp ALTER COLUMN SchemaName VARCHAR(XXXX)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the root cause of this issue.
Actually I was trying to insert `sysname` data type value into `varchar()`.
So must specify proper length to hold [sysname](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240(v=sql.105).aspx) data type.

Comment: ah you already found the problem.. I see +1 - little hint, sysname is basically nvarchar(128)

Answer (score 0):

Your target table is not sufficient to hold the data that you are trying to insert. It seems your target size would be varchar(256) but you have given varchar(10). Just extend the column size to resolve this issue.

Run this DDL

```
Alter table temp alter column SchemaName varchar(256)
```

Comment: I don't understand when the data length already mentioned is 12 so what's the point using 'varchar(256)'

Answer (score 0):

This error come when your column has less size them. 
Update size of your column.