# Error while passing table type with other params from C# to SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm passing a table type with few other parameters from C# to stored procedure but I'm getting error as-

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Below is the type defined in SQL-

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UT_ExcludedStates2] AS TABLE(
[StateID] [int] NULL,
[StateInitial] [varchar](2) NULL,  
[IsActive] [int] NULL
)
```

Datatable defined in C#-

```
Dim dt1 As DataTable = New DataTable("TableChanged")
                dt1.Columns.Add("StateID", GetType(System.Int32))
                dt1.Columns.Add("StateInitial", GetType(System.String))
                dt1.Columns.Add("IsActive", GetType(System.Int32))
```

Here I'm passing to stored procedure-

```
Dim oSqlParam(9) As SqlParameter
                oSqlParam(0) = New SqlParameter("@RecId", RecordId)
                oSqlParam(1) = New SqlParameter("@RecName", recordName)
                oSqlParam(2) = New SqlParameter("@DealCode", dealCode)
                oSqlParam(3) = New SqlParameter("@CompanyNumber", CompanyNumber)
                oSqlParam(4) = New SqlParameter("@Active", Active)
                oSqlParam(5) = New SqlParameter("@ExcludeAllPlans", excludeAllPlans)
                oSqlParam(6) = New SqlParameter("@ExcludeAllStates", excludeAllStates)
                oSqlParam(7) = New SqlParameter("@ModifiedBy", ModifiedBy)
                oSqlParam(8) = New SqlParameter("@planCode", strPlanCodes)
                oSqlParam(9) = New SqlParameter("@UT_ExcludedStates", dtStates)

                DataSupplier.ConnectOpen(ConnectString())
                iIsUpdate = DataSupplier().GetScalarValueFromStoredProc2("PROC1", oSqlParam)
                DataSupplier().ConnectClose()
                Return iIsUpdate
```

Procedure's parameters are following-

```
@RecId int=0,
@RecName varchar(30),
@DealCode varchar(30),
@CompanyNumber varchar(5),
@Active int,
@ExcludeAllPlans int,
@ExcludeAllStates int,
@ModifiedBy varchar(30)='',
@planCode varchar(200)='',
@UT_ExcludedStates UT_ExcludedStates2 READONLY
```

I've gone through several posts on the same problem but nothing helped. Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error, string or binary data would be truncated when trying to insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591473/error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-when-trying-to-insert)

Comment: Somewhere in the data table you have a value in the `StateInitial` column that is longer than 2 chars.

Comment: @RuiJarimba this is not duplicate bcoz the link you have referred doen't solve my problem. I've checked all the corresponding fields of SQL.

Comment: @LogicalDesk I believe it is exactly the same issue. Check the accepted answer in that post, and double-check all your fields and parameters length. You might need to do some debugging as well in order to see the values that are set in these fields

Comment: @ZoharPeled I tried by changing [StateInitial] [varchar](2) NULL to [StateInitial] [varchar](max) NULL but still got the same error.

Comment: Set the `DataTable` `StateInitial` column `MaxLength` propery to 2 to match the TVP type. The error might not be due to the TVP but due to a table modified in the proc code with smaller column type than the source data.

Comment: @RuiJarimba I tried by setting all sql fields to max in SP so that they receive any size but same error occurred.

Comment: @DanGuzman I tried by changing "StateInitial" column to dt1.Columns.("StateInitial").MaxLength=2 but still getting the same error. Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: As I mentioned, the error may be unrelated to the TVP. Check all source parameters and columns to ensure they match the data type and length of the target. The reason for the error is the actual source length exceeds the target. You'll need to post the proc code and other DDL if you need more help.

Comment: You should fully specify the SQL parameters with the database column type and size (where applicable), e.g. `oSqlParam(1) = New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@RecName", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Size = 30, .Value = recordName}`.

Comment: It might be other varchar parameters, I assumed it was the data table since the title of the question included the table valued parameter, but it just as well might be any other varchar value that's too long for a column.