# Bulk insert Unicode Text in SQL Server 2008 results in "unexpected end of file"

Tags: sql-server, windows, csv, bulk

I'm trying to create a script that updates a table using a unicode text previously saved in Excel.

My SQL Server version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 \<X64\> (Build 9200: )
```

The table is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ActualizarMasiva
(
    [barra] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [articulo] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [und] [decimal](28, 0) NULL,
    [costo] [float] NULL,
    [precio1] [float] NULL,
    [margen1] [float] NULL,
    [precio4] [float] NULL,
    [margen4] [float] NULL,
    tipo_imp [varchar](50) NULL,
    [capacidad] [float] NULL,
    tipo_licor [varchar](50) NULL,
    grado_al [decimal](10,2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Note that any column can be null except for the first one, and I used `varchar(50)` even when the data is smaller following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591473/error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-when-trying-to-insert).

I have a format file, with the following information:

[image: Format specifying the format and lenghts]

I've read these articles from Microsoft:

[Use BULK INSERT and XML Format File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

[Structure of Non-XML Format Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/non-xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

[Specify Field and Row Terminators (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).

And this is the error message after running the bulk insert:

[image: Error message]

The log says:

> Row 39 File Offset 7415 ErrorFile Offset 0 - HRESULT 0x80004005

But Row 39 has the same format as any other, so I'm not really seeing the error perse.

I've tried using ROWTERMINATOR =  '\r' or '\n' and any combination of those two together. I've also tried changing the prefix length and use \0 for the Null terminator if that would be the case. I also checked with Notepad++ and here's a print of it:

[image: Unicode Text]

Here's the bulk insert script:

```
BULK INSERT ActualizarMasiva
FROM 'C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\CSV corrida masiva\actualizarmasivaprueba.txt'
WITH (
    FIRSTROW = 2,   --Contiene headers
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\CSV corrida masiva\FormatoActualizacionMasiva.fmt',
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\CSV corrida masiva\errorLog'
    );
```

Maybe I'm missing something but right now I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Please note that SQL Server 2008 R2 was [end-of-life](https://endoflife.date/mssqlserver) about *nine years ago*. The recent documentation you find may not be applicable.

Comment: Where did you found \0n as field separator

Comment: Second the "Why the \0 null terminator?" question. Also, the account under which the SQL Server service executes isn't likely to have file system access to anything inside the `C:\Users\Administrador` folder tree - have you tried moving the data, error and format files to a common area that it might be able to access?

Comment: Why does the question title include "Bulk insert Unicode text" when there doesn't seem to be any Unicode text involved? SQL Server 2008 R2 doesn't include any support for UTF-8 encoding so if you need to read in Unicode text you'll need to use `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` data types on your columns and read from data files that are UCS-2 or UTF-16 encoded.

Comment: siggemannen and @AlwaysLearning the "null terminator" was the last thing I changed to see if it worked. It didn't, but the result is the same using the other alternatives that I tried (\n, \r, \n\r, \r\n). 

Also, the text is saved using Excel's option "Unicode Text" as in the only option that doesn't mess up the special characters when I try to import them to SQL. I've tried other methods, that's not the main point of this post.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm well aware, but using the format text suggested by Microsoft, my version is one of the options for the version parameter. It should work if everything else is okay.

Comment: @ZuilHappy if they're Unicode Text files from Excel (I won't get into how good Excel is at clobbering international and scientific characters) why are you using the `DATAFILETYPE = 'char'` option? That's telling [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql#datafiletype---char--native--widechar--widenative-) that the file is using 8-bit OEM/codepage characters, have you tried `DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'` instead?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning didn't help using 'widechar'. Even tried changing the column type to nvarchar and the format to SQLNCHAR. But the error still remains, now saying:

`Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2, column 1 (barra).`