# The data type text cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I have a table

- Id (PK)
- Owner int
- DescriptionText text

which is joined to another table

- Id (FK)
- Participant int

The Owner can be a Participant, and if it is, the same reference (into user table) is in Owner and Participant. So I did:

```
SELECT TableA.Id,TableA.Owner,TableA.Text
FROM TableA
WHERE TableA.Owner=@User
UNION
SELECT TableA.Id,TableA.Owner.TableA.Text
FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON (TableA.Id=TableB.Id)
WHERE TableB.Participant = @User
```

This query should return all distinct data sets where a certain @User is either Owner or Participant or both.

And it would, if SQL Server wouldn't throw

> The data type text cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable.

Since Id is a PK, and Text is from the same table, why would SQL Server want to compare Text at all?

I can use `UNION ALL` to stop duplicate detection, but can I circumvent this without losing the distinctness of the results?

Comment: Hey, is your dataset distinct otherwise?  Only one owner of a table, and only registered as a participant once?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Correct way**

Stop using [`TEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) it is obsolete. Alter table schema.

> **ntext, text, and image** data types will be removed in a future version
>   of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. **Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.**

**Workaround**

Cast to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`:

```
SELECT TableA.Id,TableA.Owner, CAST(TableA.DescriptionText AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
FROM TableA
WHERE TableA.Owner=@User
UNION
SELECT TableA.Id,TableA.Owner, CAST(TableA.DescriptionText AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON (TableA.Id=TableB.Id)
WHERE TableB.Participant = @User
```

Comment: I have switched the schema to `nvarchar(max)` and the query works. Thanks for pointing out that `text` is obsolete.

Comment: By the way, is there any disadvantage/drawback of the recommended data types over the obsoleted ones that I should be aware of? Is nvarchar(MAX) counting towards maximum row size, do they impact indexing or query speed?

Comment: @Alexander  I would say that newer datatypes are better. `TEXT` is available only because backward compatibility. You should use `MAX` when it is needed. For example does your description really needs 2GB text? Maybe 4000 will be absolutely sufficient. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133946/nvarcharmax-vs-ntext

Comment: 32K-64K would be sufficient, but I think varchar takes no number exceeding 4000.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you