# Why is this join taking so long?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have the following query that I am running on my database server but it takes about **30 seconds** to run and I can't work out why this is.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[PackageInstance] AS packInst
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[PackageDefinition] AS packageDef 
    ON packInst.[PackageDefinitionID] = packageDef.[PackageDefinitionID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[PackageInstanceContextDef] AS contextDef 
   ON packInst.[PackageInstanceID] = contextDef.[PackageInstanceID]
```

This produced the following execution plan which to me looks to be good....so I can't understand why it takes so much time to execute where the resulting data is only 100,000 records (which should be a walk in the park for SQL Server).

[image: SQL Server Execution Plan]

Any ideas what could be causing this long execution time?

I have looked at the query in Profiler to see what the stats where on it and they are as follows:

```
CPU - 4711
Reads - 744453
Writes - 9
Duration - 26329
```

The following are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PackageDefinition](
    [PackageDefinitionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ts] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [ProgramID] [int] NULL,
    [VendorID] [int] NULL,
    [PackageExecutionTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [PackageDefinitionStatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsInternal] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [dbo].[D_Name] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [dbo].[D_Description] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PublishedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [OwnerUserGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ProcessDefinitionMainID] [int] NULL,
    [KeyInfoHtml] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DescriptionHtml] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [WhatToExpectHtml] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [BestPracticesHtml] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [RecommendedJourneysHtml] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [RequiresSLAAgreement] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SLAFileAssetID] [int] NULL,
    [ImageDataID] [int] NULL,
    [VideoHtml] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [VideoAssetID] [int] NULL,
    [UseMapCosts] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CostMin] [money] NOT NULL,
    [CostMax] [money] NOT NULL,
    [LandingPageVisitCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [dbo].[D_IsDeleted] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedByUserGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [OrderHtml] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PackageDefinition] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PackageDefinitionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PackageInstance](
    [PackageInstanceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ts] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [PackageDefinitionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PackageStatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [dbo].[D_Description] NOT NULL,
    [CampaignID] [int] NULL,
    [MarketingPlanID] [int] NULL,
    [CountryID] [int] NULL,
    [DateEntered] [datetime] NULL,
    [DateExecuted] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProcessID] [int] NULL,
    [OrderedByUserGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [RequestedByUserGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [SLAEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PackageInstance] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PackageInstanceID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PackageInstanceContextDef](
    [PackageInstanceContextDefID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ts] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [PackageInstanceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContextObjectDefID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EnteredFieldValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [SelectedListValueID] [int] NULL,
    [AssetIdsString] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SelectedListValueIdsString] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ContextObjectFieldName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PackageInstanceContextDef] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PackageInstanceContextDefID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Any CPU/disk contention from other processes?

Comment: What's the execution count for the index scan on PackageInstanceContextDef?  (it's in the tooltip)

Comment: Any sort warnings in Profiler? What if you try at `read uncommitted` isolation level? Maybe encountering blocking. @Andomar - It will be 1. Merge Join only processes each input once.

Comment: 744,453 reads is > 5GB of data. How wide are these rows? Also might you have heavy fragmentation?

Comment: @MartinSmith - I have just tried setting the isolation level to read uncommitted and that didn't change the time. I think this is because there are no other queries being run on the database at the moment.

Comment: @Penfold - Yes I posted that as a suggestion before you put the IO stats up. What are the table definitions?

Comment: @MartinSmith - Forgive the question but how do you work out the relation between 744,453 and 5Gb? I take it that this is something to do with page size?!  My database is currently 2Gb in size so I have no idea how it could be reading 5Gb to get the result!! :(

Comment: @Penfold Assuming a logical read is an 8KB page. Logical reads are reported differently for work tables though so that assumption isn't always correct. Doesn't seem that it should be reading the same page more than once in that plan. Can you try `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and post the result of that? And your table definitions!

Comment: @MartinSmith - The results from the IO stats are as follows: 
Table 'PackageInstanceContextDef'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1313, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'PackageInstance'. Scan count 1, logical reads 234, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'PackageDefinition'. Scan count 1, logical reads 25, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 742610, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: @Penfold - It is all those `max` columns that are killing performance. [There might be something in this article of relevance](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/23/Advanced-TSQL-Tuning-Why-Internals-Knowledge-Matters.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turned out to be what @MartinSmith suggested.  Because the PackageDefinition table contained about 8 NVARCHAR(MAX) columns, when the resulting join was created and that was over 100k rows, this was causing the varchar(max) values to be re-read over and over and they exist in out of row pages.  Hence the large number of logical reads.

Thanks all for your support, just have to figure out to make the entity framework produce the query that I want.

Comment: Did you try my answer? Was curious to know whether retrieving the large columns after the sort operation even at the expense of accessing `PackageDefinition` twice would improve things?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `*` in `SELECT *`

It will always scan because you ask for all columns. And do you have clustered indexes?

Comment: Unfortunatly what I am trying to do is find out why my Linq-to-Entities query is taking so long so I have no control over which fields I can select so I need them all!! :(  In a production version, I would remove the star and add the columns by name.  There are clustered indexes on the Primary Key of each of the tables.

Comment: @Penfold: you are asking us to help with a test query then has SELECT *...?

Comment: Yes, I could list out every one of the columns if you like but there are a few of them and I didn't think that it would help seeing as I wan't all of them.

Comment: You do not by definintion need all columns as you have joins where the same data is in mulitple coloumns. SELECT * is a SQL antipattern and should never be used in production code. If your ORM can't handle that it is a poor tool and should not be used.

Comment: @HLGEM I totally agree with you on using SELECT * in production code and that an ORM should be able to restrict the data being returned. However, what I am saying here is not that I want to user SELECT * or that the Entity Framework is not capable of working out what it needs, but rather that I used SELECT * to make the statement easier to view as there would be about 50 columns that the framework returns.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you add the following index...

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON  PackageDefinition(PackageDefinitionID)
```

...and try the following to reduce the width of the data going into the sort?

```
SELECT packInst.*,
       packageDef2.*,
       contextDef.*
FROM   [dbo].[PackageInstance] AS packInst
       INNER MERGE JOIN [dbo].[PackageDefinition] AS packageDef
         ON packInst.[PackageDefinitionID] = packageDef.[PackageDefinitionID]
       LEFT OUTER MERGE JOIN [dbo].[PackageInstanceContextDef] AS contextDef
        ON packInst.[PackageInstanceID] = contextDef.[PackageInstanceID]
       INNER MERGE JOIN [dbo].[PackageDefinition] AS packageDef2
        ON packageDef.[PackageDefinitionID] = packageDef2.[PackageDefinitionID]
```

OF course `*` should not be used as even if you need all columns you definitely won't need the same columns twice as the result of the `JOIN` but this is just to maintain the semantics of your original query.